# How to implement LINQ functions in a VB.NET collection class

Tags: vb.net, linq, iqueryable

I have a collection class which is a wrapper for a

```
List(Of MyClass)
```

And the collection class implements things like add, count etc

```
Private lst As List(Of MyClass)

Public Function Count() As Long
    Return lst.Count
End Function
```

I want to add the ability to do Linq queries on the collection class. So  client could do something like this:

```
dim c as New MyCollectionClass
c.Add(New MyClass With {.Name = "XXX"})
c.Add(New MyClass With {.Name = "XXX"})
c.Add(New MyClass With {.Name = "YYYY"})

Dim nc As MyCollectionClass = c.GroupBy(function(x) x.Name)
```

How do I implement the groupby function and all the other Linq functions (select, filter, distinct, orderby etc) ? I've implemented iQueryable in the class.

I'm confused on how to declare it and its parameters and implementation etc. I've tried a few things like

```
Public Function GroupBy(f As Func(Of MyClass)) As IEnumerable
    Return lst.GroupBy(Function(x As MyClass) f(x))
End Function
```

But thats just a syntax error, and I'm just stuck now :)  thanks

FWIW this is what I've done for Iqueryable:

```
Implements IEnumerable, IQueryable

Private lst As New List(Of MyClass)

Public ReadOnly Property Expression As Expression Implements IQueryable.Expression
    Get
        Return lst.AsQueryable.Expression
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property ElementType As Type Implements IQueryable.ElementType
    Get
        Return lst.AsQueryable.ElementType
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property Provider As IQueryProvider Implements IQueryable.Provider
    Get
        Return lst.AsQueryable.Provider
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: What does `I've implemented iQueryable in the class.` mean? And why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: I assumed from googling the errors that this would solve it, but apparently not :)

Comment: And you know that `MyClass` isn't a valid type for your list?

Comment: ^^ don't know what you mean there. It is a valid type for a list. You can do a List(of AnyClassOrTypeYouLike) !

Comment: But `MyClass` is a reserved keyword. It won't compile with `MyClass`.

Comment: Oh sorry, ok. I wasn't using that name in my code. Just on here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to re-implement `Linq` extensions (`Select`, `GroupBy`, etc.). You just need to implement `IEnumerable(Of MyClass)`, then standard `Linq` extensions will work with your class automatically.

An example of `IEnumerable(Of ...)` implementation:

```
Public Class MyCollection
    Implements IEnumerable(Of MyClass1)


    Private lst As New List(Of MyClass1)

    Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of MyClass1) Implements IEnumerable(Of MyClass1).GetEnumerator
        Return lst.GetEnumerator()
    End Function

    Private Function IEnumerable_GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
        Return DirectCast(lst, IEnumerable).GetEnumerator()
    End Function

End Class
```

And usage:

```
Dim collection = New MyCollection
...
Dim count = collection.Count()
```